# Call to a member function count() on a non-object. From one .php to another

Tags: php

So I have been getting this fatal error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/index.php on line 6". I will just give you a large portion go my code just in case.

Here is my DB.php

```
<?php
class DB {
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo, 
                $_query, 
                $_error = false, 
                $_results, 
                $_count = 0;

private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));      
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }   
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} * FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT*', $table, $where);
}

public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
}

public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count() {
    return $this->_count;
}

}
```

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

if(!$user->count()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {
   echo 'OK!';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$user` is not an object, check what it is by `var_dump($user);`. And because it is not an object, you cannot call its method by `->count()`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `get()` method that will lead to an sql statement of:

```
SELECT* * FROM ....
```

You can remove the `*` from your `get` method or remove it from your `action` method and add a space in your `get` method.

You probably need the latter option for your `delete` method to work:

```
public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
```

and:

```
...
$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
...
```

Apart from that you are assuming that PDO will throw exceptions, but you need to tell PDO that first.

You can add that option in your constructor:

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'),
                      Config::get('mysql/username'),
                      Config::get('mysql/password'),
                      $options);
```

Now PDO will throw an exception when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The [error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/1144203) is telling you that `$user` is a non-object. Looking at the codes of your `action()` function, my guess is that your `$user` is set to `false`, because of a SQL syntax error caused by:

```
public function get($table, $where) {
  return $this->action('SELECT*', $table, $where); // there is an extra asterisk here

}
```

And

```
$sql = "{$action} * FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
```

Notice the extra asterisk in your `SELECT` clause.